# Is there any good free Gantt Chart controls for .net winforms?

Tags: .net, controls, gantt-chart

The question is in the title. I'm looking for a free gantt chart control to use in a .net application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you check out [Microsoft Chart Controls](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=130F7986-BF49-4FE5-9CA8-910AE6EA442C&displaylang=en)

Comment: Wow, I did not knew about these. It's exactly what I was looking for, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[Check this out](http://www.designinginteractive.com/code/how-to-build-a-gantt-chart-with-the-google-charts-api/)

It uses the Google Charts API to create a Gantt chart